# Не получается воспользоваться ни одной библиотекой в виртуальном окружении в Python VS code

Tags: python-3.x

После создания внутреннего окружения, решил установить пару библиотек, включая numpy.Пытаясь написать строчку кода import numpy as np numpy подчеркивается, а в PROBLEMS выходит строка: Не удается разрешить импорт "numpy".Так происходит с любой другой библиотекой, я новичок полный и поэтому не знаю что нужно делать чтобы докопаться до решения, прошу помощи у мастеров разработки!)Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: в виртуальное окружение также надо инсталлировать модули.

Comment: так я и инсталлировал в мой venv и даже воспользовавшись source python их там находит, но как только я пытаюсь прописать строчку кода, обращаясь к хоть одному из модулей, возникает проблема

Comment: ммм, любопытно, и это означает, что виртуальный питон доступен только в консоли с активированным venv. а дотнет его никогда не увидит, хотя можно поискать, как запустить venv из дотнетовского приложения. для начала попробуйте без venv/